# odbc_result(): Field ID not found in

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to fetch data from MSSQL database and printing. But i am getting tnis error," Warning: odbc_result(): Field ID not found in ".
My code is as below.

```
<?php

$dsn="LocalServer";
$username="sa";
$password="12345678";

$sqlconnect=odbc_connect($dsn,$username,$password);
if($sqlconnect){echo"connected";}
else{echo"not";}
$sqlquery="SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000),CONVERT(VARBINARY(8000),Name)) AS StudentID FROM StudentInfo;";
$process=odbc_exec($sqlconnect, $sqlquery);

 while(odbc_fetch_row($process)){
 $row = odbc_result($process,"Name");



 echo $row; 

 }
 odbc_close($sqlconnect);


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL has that column defined as StudentID

Comment: Thanks. i am trying to covert Name column to varchar from image formate. but my code is not working plz help me.

Comment: i would think an image would not convert to varchar, why not convert to NVARCHAR,what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I did not use MSSQL ever. but i have a database which is showing <binary> in Name column so i want to get information from this column. thats why i was converting it to varchar. So help me i dont know how to get info from this column.

Comment: in order to get "info" from this BINARY column you need to know what the BINARY data is so you can transform it.  If it's an image then it's an image... not clear what you are trying to display... if you want to display it as an image then you need to read the column as binary and stream those bytes to an image control.

Comment: There is some names like sheraz, ahmad etc. i want to get them.

Comment: your not explaining this well.

Comment: Sory, i am not getting what you want to ask. i only know that there is data like text and names of students.